# Mapping Wikidata QID to Wikipedia CurID

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata, linked-data

Two questions:

1. How can I map `QID` from Wikidata to English Wikipedia `CurID` using dumps?
2. Which dump to use?

I am not looking for an API based solution, as I want to generate this mapping for all wikipedia entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to fetch the [page_props table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_props_table) from the [database dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html) and look for the `wikibase_item` property.